# If statement and split function

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-formulas

My memo line that looks something like this:

```
Return: #999 100.00\NSF|Balance=$242.00. Available Balance=$50.00`
```

or

```
Return: #888 45.90\WD REST.
```

I need it to return everything before the `|` if there is one, *or* the whole memo line if there isn't a `|`.  Right now I have two formulas that give everything before the `|` or nothing if there isn't a `|`

```
memo1: left({table.memo},instr(table.memo},"|"))

memo2: replace({@Memo1},"|"," ")
```

How can I configure this such that if a `|` is present, return `@Memo2`, else return `{table.memo}`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, just make one more formula like this:

```
IF instr({table.memo},"|")>0
THEN {@Memo2}
ELSE {table.memo}
```

This displays one formula or the other based on the presence of that vertical line character.

Comment: When I put this into formula int tells me that I need a boolean in the first line. Any suggestions?

Comment: @bdancer88 Ah my bad - Spent too much time using a different language. I've amended the formula to include a `> 0 ` which will make it valid.

Answer (score 0):

I would use an `if` statement with `instr`:

```
memo1: left({table.memo},instr(table.memo},"|"))
memo2: replace({@Memo1},"|"," ")

if instr(table.memo} > 0 
   left({table.memo},instr(table.memo},"|"))
else 
   replace({@Memo1},"|"," ")
```

Please try something like that.  (I did not check the syntax, so please check my work.)

[Example for if](https://www.kb.blackbaud.com/articles/Article/52447)